# What's the meaning of "talpa" when used to describe a person?

Tags: word-meaning, meaning

As per title, what's the meaning of "talpa" when used to describe a person?

Example:

> John è una talpa

Comment: You could have found it in any Italian vocabulary, and the corresponding figurative meaning exists in English too (“mole” as “a spy who gradually achieves an important position within the security defences of a country” or “someone within an organization who anonymously betrays confidential information”).

Comment: More context would be useful to understand the intended meaning.

Answer (score 9):

The word *talpa* may refer to an informer or spy; somebody who passes information profiting from their workplace. The word *mole* is used with the same meaning in English.

From the [Treccani dictionary](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/talpa)

> Con uso traslato (alla cui diffusione ha contribuito anche la traduzione fr. *La taupe*, 1974, e ital. *La talpa*, 1975, del titolo di un romanzo inglese di John Le Carré, *Tinker, tailor, soldier, spy*, del 1974), informatore clandestino, infiltrato (o reclutato da un’organizzazione, spesso eversiva o terroristica) tra il personale di uffici pubblici o privati, spec. presso i ministeri, uffici giudiziarî, servizî di sicurezza, allo scopo di raccogliere notizie riservate o segrete: *la t. del Palazzo di Giustizia*; *si pensa che la fuga di notizie sia dovuta alla presenza di una t. nel ministero della Difesa*. Anche, funzionario, impiegato o tecnico infiltrato, o assoldato, tra il personale di un’azienda per carpirne i segreti industriali o commerciali a vantaggio di un concorrente.

Answer (score 8):

In colloquial language it also means you're almost blind, like the animal "talpa" (mole). But in this case it's usually used in a comparison: you're as blind as/like a mole (sei (cieco) come una talpa).

This meaning ("persona che vede poco") is mentioned at [De Mauro dictionary](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/talpa), giving these examples:

> *non può guidare, è una talpa*

and also

> *essere cieco come una talpa*.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: In fact, in Stefano Benni's book *Pane e tempesta* there is a character who is called "la Talpa" because he's almost blind.

Comment: This meaning ("persona che vede poco") is mentioned at [De Mauro dictionary](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/talpa), giving these examples: *non può guidare, è una talpa* and also *essere cieco come una talpa*.

Comment: I have included the content of my comment in the answer because I think it's a good idea trying always to give a reference.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what is explained by @egreg and @Liuka, 
according to [De Mauro dictionary](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/talpa), the word "talpa" can also have these meanings referring to a person:

> persona caratterizzata da scarsa intelligenza e da ottusità: *non capisci niente, sei una vera talpa*

that is, a person characterized by poor intelligence and dullness,

and also

> persona chiusa, poco interessata ai fatti esterni

that is, someone closed, with little interest in external facts.

Comment: In the short story *Casa d'altri*, by Silvio D'Arzo, one can read this sentence: «Lasciamo in pace la vecchia **talpa** oramai.» By the description of the old woman to which the expression "la vecchia talpa" refers, it's clear that here "talpa" has the meaning of someone closed, with little interest in external facts.