# Significato di "spolverarsi il cuore"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel racconto *Casa d'altri* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> «Bene bene. Lasciamo in pace la vecchia talpa oramai. **Spolveriamoci il cuore** e non pensiamoci piú».

Dalla descrizione che se ne fa nel libro, mi è chiaro che "vecchia talpa" fa riferimento alla definizione di talpa come "persona chiusa, poco interessata ai fatti esterni" che appare nel [dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/talpa) e di cui si è parlato in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/8809/707) a un'altra domanda. Comunque non riesco a capire il senso dell'espressione "spolverarsi il cuore" nel brano precedente. Ho cercato alla voce "cuore" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato niente al riguardo. Potreste spiegarmelo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leggi il passaggio da te indicato come **libera il cuore dalla polvere che lo ricopre** e non pensarci più.

In senso figurato spolverare vuol dire ripulire e quindi alleggerire il cuore dai pensieri che lo affliggono.